# Angular js: Accessing the 'arguments' property of a function is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The below client side code throws error "Accessing the 'arguments' property of a function is not allowed in strict mode".

```
 $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: window.apiUrl,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },            
            data: result,
        }).then(function (res) {
            debugger;
            console.log('succes !', res.data);
            $scope.ResetData();
            window.alert("Successfully created");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            debugger;
            console.log('error...', err);
        });
```

But if i add the below parameter it works

```
`headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },`
```

but it is sending the entire page to api, instead of only json data

Is it related ACAS propblem, because my api and website is same url with different port. any suggestions or help?

Comment: I've removed the C# tag for you.

Comment: I don't see where `arguments` is being accessed